# Search inside XML file and get sibling nodes

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have and Xml file that contains `filename` and its `checksum`. I want to get  its `innerText`. This is the sample xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FileChecksums>
  <file>
    <filepath>930cdc93-5df2-4262-ba31-824e83404a2c.jpg</filepath>
    <checksum>C4D9F0D47FF88130ABF0DA3C5351D71938C705F6602AE412D946AD5C74850837</checksum>
  </file>
  <file>
    <filepath>7dd01bb9-3f35-442c-8840-1540632973f3.png</filepath>
    <checksum>27EA8D4378DC8DB92F3D9ADA887E124BECAED47816FD3FFE49A4027362AF0FDC</checksum>
  </file>
</FileChecksums>
```

If there's a match at the `<checksum>`'s inner text, I would like to get the corresponding `<filepath>`'s inner text.

This is the code: (It will only read all  tag)

```vb
Private Sub LocateFromChecksum(chksum As String)
    Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
    xmlDoc.Load("checksum.xml")
    'search here?
    For Each node As XmlNode In xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("checksum")
        Debug.WriteLine(node.InnerText)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You want to look at XPath. You don't need to write any loops to select a certain node from an XML document.

Comment: @Tomalak So like this?`doc.SelectNode("FileChecksums/file[checksum='somechecksum']/filepath").InnerText`

Comment: Exactly! `//file[checksum='somechecks‌​um']/filepath` would be a bit more convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the mighty [Linq-to-Xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384460.aspx).

It has some nice syntactic sugar for VB .NET, e.g. you can access xml-elements with angle brackets: `<filepath>`.

Also, as the name suggest, you can simply use linq to filter your xml.

Example:

```
Dim x As XDocument = XDocument.Load("checksum.xml")
Dim sampleChecksum = "27EA8D4378DC8DB92F3D9ADA887E124BECAED47816FD3FFE49A4027362AF0FDC"

Dim xFile = x.<FileChecksums>.<file>.Where(Function(c) c.<checksum>.Value = sampleChecksum)
'Or even (same result)':
xFile = x...<file>.Where(Function(c) c.<checksum>.Value = sampleChecksum)

If xFile.Any() Then
    Debug.WriteLine(xFile.<filepath>)
End If
```

You can even omit the `.Value` in the last line since there exist some built-in value conversions for XElements.

Comment: This syntactic sugar called [XML Axis Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384769.aspx). And if you create and add your xml file schema to the project - you will get IntelliSense help too